# UITableViewCell separatorInset reset after scrolling or select a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set the following settings for my cells

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 100)]; 
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 100);
```

The separator line inset works fine when it first loaded. However, as soon as I start scrolling or select a cell, the separator line inset of the **last cell of each section** would reset itself and take up the full width of the screen.

Anyone know what is going on?

While googling around to find my answer; I've stumbled across someone that has similar issue - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6523422

Comment: What XCode version that you are using? Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: 5.1.1 and no autolayout

Comment: Where do you set cell's separatorInset? Try to do it in `willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath:`